# bidirectional link to Station -Access point and data send in mininet-wifi

Tags: ip, simulation, mininet

i have a simple mininet topology with one station and on access point.
i have set the ip for each one.
However, i can ping from sta1 to ap1 but no from ap1 to sta1.
According to mininet documentation the addLink() is bidirectional.
Also , i notice that if i use ip like 127.0.0.x in the station and the access point it work. Why is this happen?
My final goal is to send data (e.g. hello) from Stations (more that one) to access point via nc or sockets. (using the 127.0.0.x ip nc not work correct)

```
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mn_wifi.cli import CLI
from mn_wifi.net import Mininet_wifi
def topology():
    net = Mininet_wifi()
    # Create weather station hosts
    sta1=net.addStation('sta1', ip='10.0.0.2')
    # Create access point
    ap1 = net.addAccessPoint('ap1', ssid='ssid1',ip='10.0.0.1', mode='g', channel='1')
    net.configureWifiNodes()
    # Create links between station and access point
    net.addLink(ap1,sta1)
    # Start network
    net.build()
    net.start()
    ap1.start([])
    # Start CLI
    CLI(net)
    # Stop network
    net.stop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel('info')
    topology()
```

Thanks in advance!